# ng-repeat issue with JSON Object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I'm trying to print the keys and values of a simple JSON object inside an HTML table with ng-repeat but not able to print it on the html page. The JSON object has been received from the backend and am trying to populate that in the frontend. I understand that I am doing a silly mistake somewhere but can't understand where.

**JSON Object**

```
json_data ={
    user1 : "matt",
    user2 : "kim",
    user3 : "Tim"
}

$scope.rows = json_data;
```

**HTML code**..

```
   <table ng-if="displayTable">
        <caption>Results</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in rows">
                <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Can't understand what silly mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Your code is correct, most probably the condition in your ng-if is false.

Comment: Even after removing ng-if it is not working. I am using angular version 1.6.9. Is that causing problem?

Comment: your html is invalid.  you have an extra closing `</tr>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try {{rows.key}} and {{rows.value}}. Although I don't thing this is the answer. Give it a try..

Alternative ly you can try to see if it works with just one , either key or value...

Answer (score 0):

First at all, the (key, value) is more well represented by (index, value).
A correct version of this piece of code will output this:

> 0    {"user1":"matt","user2":"kim","user3":"Tim"}

which 0 is the first index of an array and the json is the entire value.
So, i guess you are using a bad approach. 
Try to modify your array to something like that:

```
$scope.rows = [
   {key: 'user1', user: 'matt'},
   {key: 'user1', user: 'kim'},
   {key: 'user1', user: 'Tim'},
];
```

And modify your HTML to:

```
<table ng-if="displayTable">
    <caption>Results</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td> {{row.key}} </td> <td> {{ row.user }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```